# add.indicator alternative possible for quantmod?

Tags: quantmod

Instead of using [these](http://www.quantmod.com/documentation/TA.html) indicators can I give my custom indicator input as a column in quantmod or I should write my indicator by myself?  (My indicator is rather complex and I do not have enough knowledge of R.)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to `quantstrat::add.indicator`. This doesn't have anything to do with quantmod.

You are not required to code your own indicator. You can include your indicator in the `mktdata` object, and then call `applySignals` and `applyRules` individually.